# Initializing a struct array in a class constructor c++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I try to solve this bank account problem:

[image]

I want to create a bank account program using a binary tree, so I'm using a `struct` to enter the account info, however, the problem which I'm facing is that I want to create an array of `struct` so that when a client wants to have more than one account I want to increment the struct array to enter the second account info

So the main idea is I want multiple accounts in the same binary tree node using a `struct` array.
Does anyone have an idea how I can do this and initialize the array in `main()` every time I want to create a new account to the same person

Here is the struct's content

```
struct info {
    int id;
    string name;
    int balance;
};

class Node
{
public:
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    info myarray[3];
    Node()
    {
        left = 0;
        right = 0;
    }
    Node(Node * l, Node * r, int Id, int Balance, string Name)
    {
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
};
```

I don't know how to put the values in the constructor and how to pass it to the constructor through this function

```
bool createnewaccount(int id, int balance, string name)
{
    Node *temp = root;
    Node *prev = root;
    while (temp != 0)
    {
        prev = temp;
        if (id > temp->data.id)
            temp = temp->right;
        else if (id < temp->data.id)
            temp = temp->left;
        else
            return false;
    }
    if (prev->data.id > id)
    {
        prev->left = new Node(0, 0, id, balance, name);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        prev->right = new Node(0, 0, id, balance, name);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code not images.

Comment: You can keep `std::vector<info> accounts;` inside your binary tree node. And learn about [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

According to the requirements in question 1, all operations shall be performed using a unique bank account number. So your binary tree is ordered using bank account numbers.

**General problem with your approach**

To answer question 2, you can't just add multiple account numbers in one node:  you would not be able to find the additional accounts in the tree, unless you would explore all the nodes !   Keeping the tree exactly as you've implemented it in question 1 will answer question 2.  it's just that your customer information (name) would be duplicate, and you would not be able to see the overall balance of a customer.

Several options you could consider:

1. Do nothing, and just live with the duplicate customer names (after all there's nothing in the requirements about this).
2. Say that the ID is no longer the bank ID but the customer ID.  The  account ID would then be obtained by combining the customer ID and a sequential index.  In this case you could manage a vector of accounts as you envisaged to do.  The problem is then reduced to parsing the account number to distinguish cusotmer id and index, and adding an indexing logic.
3. Keep the ID and the tree as it is.  But instead of a name, use a customer id and manage a second tree for maintaining the customers by name,  and hold a list of all the bank accounts owned by the customer (vector of bank account ids, that you could search in the first tree).

**Problems in your code**

`createnewaccount()` is flawed.  When the tree is empty (`root` is `nullptr`) you will dereference a null pointer (`prev->data`) :  this is undefined behavior.  To easiest way to address this is to add a special case right at the begin of the function:

```
if (root == nullptr) {
   root = new Node (...); 
   return true; 
}
```

Once you have solved this, you'll notice that your design is based on the assumption of one account per node.  If you want more accounts per node:

- you'd need to extend the `Node` class with functions to add additional accounts to an existing node (the constructor always create a new node).
- how would you find the node of an existing customer to add the new account to the existing node ?

**How to solve this problem correctly**

Regardless how you look at the problem, the multiple bank account per customer requires to be able to find bank account per account id as well as by customer.  This means to manage two trees: one sorted by bank accounts, and the second per customer.

I assume that this is howework, because for real code you'd never develop a binary tree, but just use a `std::map`.

So I won't do your homework for you, but here a clue:

```
struct Info {
    int id;
    string name;
    int balance;
};

class AccountNode  // for your tree of unique bank accounts 
{
public:
    AccountNode *left;
    AccountNode *right;
    Info data;  
    AccountNode () :  left(nullptr), right(nullptr) { }
    AccountNode (AccountNode *l, AccountNode *r, int Id, int Balance, string Name): 
              left(l), right(l)
    {
        data.id = Id;
        data.name = Name;  
        data.balance = Balance; 
    }
};    

class CustomerNode {   // for a second tree of unique customers
public:
    CustomerNode *left;
    CustomerNode *right;
    std::string name;   // in reality, you'd use a struct for address and contact infos
    std::vector<int> accounts;   // or an array if you're not allowed to use vector  
    CustomerNode() :  left(nullptr), right(nullptr) { }
    CustomerNode(CustomerNode * l, CustomerNode * r, string Name): 
              left(l), right(l), name(Name)   { }
};
```

With this structure, whenever you create a new account,  after having added the account in the tree of unique bank account ids, you'd search in the tree of customers if the customer exists already.  If not, you create it. In all the cases, you'd add to the node of the customer (in the second tree) the id of the new account.

You could then enrich your application with the search of a customer that would display the list of his accounts and their balance.

Answer (score 0):

for a structure that you can add and remove objects freely, you can use `vector<info>`, but if you want an array, you can do something like:

```
info *myarray;

info(int size){   //constructor
    myarray = new info[size];
    //...
}
```

if you want to expand the size of your array and maintain the current elements, you can just:

```
void expand(int currentSize, int newSize){
    info newArray = new info[newSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++){
        newArray[i] = myarray[i];
    }
    myarray = newArray;
}
```

hope that helps